Movie about a bunch of gifted students preparing for an exam
This is a movie that I saw like early 2000s. It was relatively new in 2003 and the title may end with "boys". It is about a bunch of gifted kids going to school in a pretty english setting. They are very intelligent but like to have fun in school.
A few scenes I can think of:

One student though pretty laidback in class studies his ass of at home, even while his girlfrien who I think was the principal's daughter is on his bed waiting for him to finish.
One of the boys is a little chubby and dies in a scooter accident with one of the professors who is gay.
In the end they all are happy because they top the class.


Remembered something more, it was relatively new in 2003 and the title may end with boys

Sure it's not Real Genius, starring Val Kilmer?  Although that came out in the 80's I believe.

Even the dead one is happy at the end?

The History Boys, from IMDb:

An unruly class of gifted and charming teenage boys are taught by two
  eccentric and innovative teachers, as their headmaster pushes for them
  all to get accepted into Oxford or Cambridge.

And from Wikipedia:

Off-screen, there is a motorcycle accident;

